# Could you please instruct me on how to verify a base image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

The following website states that the Docker image 'amazon-ecs-sample' is using Amazon Linux 2:

https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/amazon-ecs-sample/tags

> A sample PHP app running under Amazon Linux 2, used as a demo application for Amazon ECS

However, there's no mention of Amazon Linux 2 when I run the docker image inspect command.

The following related to the image layers might be relevant, but I don't understand it.

> Command
> ADD file:3cf811fe5073384ff1d5f405992ef7e5e452ad6d4a4cb873eee65007382f3a4a in /

```
% docker image inspect amazon/amazon-ecs-sample

[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:2d0c3b6b1a9b0f6a8bfc156261056589416ca50279e058cea8d184647fef646a",
        "RepoTags": [
            "amazon/amazon-ecs-sample:latest"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [
            "amazon/amazon-ecs-sample@sha256:36c7b282abd0186e01419f2e58743e1bf635808231049bbc9d77e59e3a8e4914"
        ],
        "Parent": "",
        "Comment": "",
        "Created": "2019-07-02T17:52:58.2707374Z",
        "Container": "adef4c75541b87a0c488d24040078994831dcc051b29863af42d91e047376ab2",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "adef4c75541b",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "80/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "APACHE_RUN_USER=apache",
                "APACHE_RUN_GROUP=apache",
                "APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "#(nop) ",
                "CMD [\"/usr/sbin/apache2\" \"-D\" \"FOREGROUND\"]"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "sha256:43a26786e7a6bcb6fa2bbc2e19ae29a1051d17a9599d13e3a4c9fa3535151003",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "DockerVersion": "18.09.2",
        "Author": "",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "80/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "APACHE_RUN_USER=apache",
                "APACHE_RUN_GROUP=apache",
                "APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/usr/sbin/apache2",
                "-D",
                "FOREGROUND"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "sha256:43a26786e7a6bcb6fa2bbc2e19ae29a1051d17a9599d13e3a4c9fa3535151003",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": null
        },
        "Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 398000155,
        "VirtualSize": 398000155,
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/34f3446d7a5fe0d41f7621aacf45efd3efb039a35cb811b3ac34bf851a0bb626/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ea8296aa2c448d3c6cb9c49853253b2fe17161cc82a851575518d871c755a284/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8de060e3d50b6acfc86910d97cd848cbe41bca4e498cbc11b6c14ca2d9ef9076/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4657e5ba9af16308664f487f5cc0f03b9e1cc20188064ad16865736844ab9600/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4657e5ba9af16308664f487f5cc0f03b9e1cc20188064ad16865736844ab9600/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4657e5ba9af16308664f487f5cc0f03b9e1cc20188064ad16865736844ab9600/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:f387c8b346c85cae37abd1f1a63015acb69f593dc425d0269f57d1012c3a81f6",
                "sha256:0079253c95d947e34db7f7ee7502f201690f705e45dbad32dc6a199b2c0ea3e5",
                "sha256:06b41922fec5c9dbba69b013bee9a2d1c4a41b1d2e719d1045afd39e55e60eff",
                "sha256:08b5344ac5932393d503b2744792eb260522af40b9e07da0aa23ab0f7fe9efaa"
            ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "LastTagTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        }
    }
]
```

This is a response from ChatGPT. Is it really not possible to verify the base image?

```
Indeed, /etc/os-release can be easily tampered with and it is not a reliable method to determine the base image from which a Docker image has been built.

As you've suggested, to verify whether a Docker image has been built from an official base image, it is important to ensure that the image was sourced from an official repository. Docker images are typically pulled from official Docker Hub repositories or other trusted repositories.

However, there aren't generally tools or means to directly verify an image's base image. This is a common challenge related to Docker's security and transparency, and it forms part of the strategies to ensure the trustworthiness and integrity of Docker images.

Securing some level of trust and security in the image can be achieved by sourcing your images from trusted sources, setting up notifications for when that image is updated, and where possible, inspecting the Dockerfile of the image.

Nevertheless, these measures do not 100% guarantee that an image is built from a trusted base image. As such, maintaining the trustworthiness and security of the Docker images you use requires ongoing management and monitoring.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## About the `ADD` line

It takes a file from the current build context and adds it to the image. `ADD` unlike `COPY` also has the capabilities to unpack tarballs before adding it to the image, we can assume that

> Command ADD file:3cf811fe5073384ff1d5f405992ef7e5e452ad6d4a4cb873eee65007382f3a4a in /

is basically unpacking and adding the contents of a tarball at the root.

## What OS it is?

If you do `cat /etc/os-release` from inside the container it will give you the following output.

[image: cat /etc/os-release]

Even though the answer from ChatGPT is valid, is there any reason for doubting AWS on this one?

Comment: Thank you. For instance, I'm looking for a way to verify if there's a list of tar files published somewhere that I could validate the files and hash.

Comment: I believe someone did this explicitly to hide certain parts of the image as to not give the whole blueprint. I don't know the purpose since this is just a sample but if that is the case you won't find it anywhere.

Comment: You're right. Since this is just a sample, it doesn't go into detail, but other major images (like Ubuntu, Nginx, etc.) may be set up for verification. I'll look into it more closely.